# Getting a not supported registry warning while using configure-docker on a supported location

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a Docker image into Google Cloud Artifact Registry in a new location: `europe-southwest1`. To do so, first, I've checked that it is supported:

```
gcloud artifacts locations list
```

As expected, a list of locations is returned, where I can see the one I'm interested on:

```
LOCATIONS
asia
asia-east1
asia-east2
asia-northeast1
asia-northeast2
asia-northeast3
asia-south1
asia-south2
asia-southeast1
asia-southeast2
australia-southeast1
australia-southeast2
europe
europe-central2
europe-north1
europe-southwest1 <--- this is the one
europe-west1
europe-west2
europe-west3
europe-west4
europe-west6
europe-west8
europe-west9
northamerica-northeast1
northamerica-northeast2
southamerica-east1
southamerica-west1
us
us-central1
us-east1
us-east4
us-east5
us-west1
us-west2
us-west3
us-west4
```

Then, I've tried to configure the new region in Docker:

```
gcloud auth configure-docker europe-southwest1-docker.pkg.dev
```

But a warning is returned stating that it is not a supported registry:

```
WARNING: Your config file at [/Users/ghostmou/.docker/config.json] contains these credential helper entries:

{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud"
  }
}
Adding credentials for: europe-southwest1-docker.pkg.dev
WARNING: europe-southwest1-docker.pkg.dev is not a supported registry
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly.
```

I've tried with other regions, for example `us-central1-docker.pkg.dev`, and it works as expected:

```
{
  "credHelpers": {
    "gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
    "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev": "gcloud"
  }
}
Adding credentials for: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
gcloud credential helpers already registered correctly
```

Can anyone help me to know if I'm doing something wrong or if there are any issues with `europe-southwest1` region?

Comment: You could try adding `--log-http` to the `gcloud` command to understand what API method is being used. It **may** be that the error is a red-herring for something else. Have you created a repository in `europe-southwest1`? That would not only provide an additional check on whether the region is supported but may also "fix" the `gcloud auth configure-docker` command. Artifact Registry needs to be enabled in the project and I wonder whether a repository needs to exist before it will validate too?

Comment: If that approach fails, you should contact Google Cloud Support or file an issue on Google's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: @DazWilkin, I've tried to obtain more information by using `--log-http`, as you suggested, but the output is the same. And, yes, I've tried creating a repository in `europe-southwest1`, but the result is the same: it is not a supported registry. I've filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236447792) in the tracker, as you also suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @ghostmou I shared my solution. can you have a look at my answer?

Comment: @RoopaM I'll try it out as soon as possible. I'm away from my computer for vacations. I've seen your response in the issue tracker, I'll check that too. Sorry for the delay, August is a tricky month :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the issue from my end following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/store-docker-container-images). But I am able to deploy docker image in `Artifact Registry` in `europe-southwest1` region.

Artifact Registry is available in the `europe-southwest1` region from [May 10, 2022](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/release-notes#May_10_2022). You may faced this issue as it was newly added region.

And I believe this issue is fixed as region is available in artifact registry

Comment: I've checked that now it is working properly for `Artifact Registry`. As @RoopaM suggests, this may have happened just because it was a new region and now the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You must update gcloud locally by executing:
gcloud components update

The gcloud SDK has the full list of created regions.
If you have an old gcloud version probably you don't see the recently created regions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).